# How to write on open event for select box in jquery using select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

How to write **on open** event for select box using select2 in jquery. I tried using .on("change"), but it gets fired once we click the option inside the selectbox. I need the event which will get triggered the moment I open the selectbox

I tried with .click, .change, .focus

```js
   

 $('#js_pdp_campus').on('select2:open', function(e) {
            
            console.log("hi");
            let $campusData = "/product-commons/getcampusdata/?baseProductCode=MBS_86530";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: $campusData,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("poc data is", data);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                }
            });
            return $campusData;
        })
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="control">
  <select name="campus" id="js_pdp_campus" class="campusDataClass js-pdp-course-finder-select bned-select-input js-enable-select-input form-control js-basic-single" role="listbox">
    <option>campus 1</option>
    <option>campus 2</option>
    <option>campus 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks  We are using select2, but I tried its all events, but not working, I tried using select2:open, its prints my console but it gets closed automatically within a second

Comment: Did you try `select2:opening` ?  https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events

Comment: I tried select2:opening, console gets printed but dropdown gets closed in 1 second

Comment: Can anyone please answer this? if I use select2:opening, why it gets closed without displaying options

Comment: *but dropdown gets closed in 1 second* this does not happen on a simple select2 (as demonstrated in an answer snippet below, so no fiddle).   If this is happening for you, then it **is caused by something else**.  Please provide a *complete* snippet that *demonstrates* the issue - a simple `.select2().on("select2:opening")` does *not* demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Added the code snippet @freedomn-m

Comment: It doesn't make any difference even after removing it.

Comment: nope. Using selectbox normally. and removed the return statement, still not working. dropdown options gets closed in a second

Comment: Have updated the code above, have given .tag file, and js file code.

Comment: Sorry.. while editing, code got messed, corrected it just now. please check

Answer (score 2):

You can use events https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
  $('.js-example-basic-single').on('select2:opening', function(e) {
    console.log("select2:opening");
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `.focus()` method for this. Try something like below.

```js
$('.sbox').focus(function() {
  console.log("WORKING..");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
<select class="sbox">
  <option>option 1</option>
  <option>option 2</option>
  <option>option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Converted to a snippet for you.  Don't use `alert` with focus as it will get stuck in an infinite loop.   This doesn't raise an event when the drop down is about to be shown - if it does for you, it's probably because you're *clicking* to get focus; I've added an input to tab-from

Comment: Thank you @freedomn-m. I don't understand why you add an input element. can you please explain?

Comment: There's a difference between `focus` and `click` - the drop down appears on click, but not on focus. If you click on the dropdown, you get the console log because you are giving focus. If you click in the input to give it focus, then press the `tab` key to give the select focus, it will fire the focus event but *not* show the drop down - so the input allows you to set focus without clicking and thus demonstrating the difference.   Equally, once focus is in the select, alt-down to show the drop down doesn't show the console.log, nor does multiple clicks to toggle it (as it's focus-only event).